# Is any collection of measurable sets a σ-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

In most textbooks it's stated that the collection $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mu^*$-measurable subsets of $X$ is a σ-algebra.

So does this mean that **any** collection of $\mu^*$-measurable subsets is a $\sigma$-algebra or only that the collection of **all** $\mu^*$-measurable subsets of X is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{A} \setminus \{X\}$ a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: In general, "the set of whatevers" means the set of all whatevers.